# How to call the constructor if the input of the String is a space or enter (nothing is there)

Tags: java, constructor

I would like to the code return "red", from the constructor color="red", if the user does not input a String (or input a space).

What happens now is that the input from the user returns blank for space or for just the enter key.

Thanks for the help!

My testing code to learn this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Testing_Constructors {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Constructor_Object object = new Constructor_Object(); 
        Constructor_Object object2 = new Constructor_Object("blue"); 

        System.out.println("object getting auto constructor color:\n" + object.getColor());
        System.out.println("object2 getting the color setted when create the obj"+
        "-> contructor need to have this.color to set parameter\n" 
                            + object2.getColor());

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input color: ");
        String color = input.nextLine();
        input.close();

        //setter for save input info
        object.setColor(color);
        object2.setColor(color);

        System.out.println("output from setter&getter\n object:\n" + object.getColor());
        System.out.println(" output from object2: " + object2.getColor());
    }
}
```

```
//OBJ CLASS

public class Constructor_Object {
    private String color;
    
    //no args constructor 
    public Constructor_Object(){
        color = "red";
    }

    
    public Constructor_Object(String color){
        this.color = color;
    }

    //setter 
    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color = color;
    }
    //getter 
    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want the constructor to do?

Comment: the scanner method scans until the next line or "\n" so you wont get a \n as an input. you can get whitespace, any combination of strings or literally an empty string "". since they are all strings and your Object takes in a string for the constructor. just pass the string as a parameter to your constructor. There is literally nothing wrong with your code?

Comment: My thought was that when the user doesn't input a real string, the constructor should be able to return something back. For example in the code I was playing with, I would like to the input return "red" if nothing is there to substitute it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what I was trying to do, in the setter of the object class I added this code to verify the for no characters and if it is empty if the user just press a lot of spaces and enter.

```
public void setColor(String color){
    if(color.length() == 0 || color.trim().isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(getColor());
    }else{
    this.color = color;
}
}
```